# back button in asp.net showing history in IE11

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, vb.net

My below code is working fine in Firefox and chrome.But when i open website in IE 11 and do login and then after that I press  logout button and then after that I press back button then my previous data(history page) is appearing.How can i solve this issue in IE11.

My logout button code is following

```
// Code disables caching by browser. Hence the back browser button
// grayed out and could not causes the Page_Load event to fire 
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-1));
Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
Response.Redirect("~/main.aspx);
```

Answer (score 0):

use this javascript on your main page which disables history of browser

```
<script type = "text/javascript" >
   function preventBack(){window.history.forward();}
    setTimeout("preventBack()", 0);
    window.onunload=function(){null};
</script>
```

Comment: my main.aspx is login page?I used in login page or after login welcome page

Comment: In which page i used this script

Answer (score 0):

Just add a line code to Page_Load():

```
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.ServerAndNoCache);
```